# Web2py postgreSQL database

Tags: python, web2py

Recently i m working on web2py postgresql i made few changes in my table added new fields with fake_migration_all = true it does updated my .table file but the two new added fields were not able to be altered in postgres database table and i also tried fake_migration_all = false and also deleted mu .table file but still it didnt help to alter my table does able two add fields in datatable

Any better solution available so that i should not drop my data table and fields should also be altered/added in my table so my data shouldn't be loast

Answer (score 0):

`fake_migrate_all` doesn't do any actual migration (hence the "fake") -- it just makes sure the metadata in the .table files matches the current set of table definitions (and therefore the actual database, assuming the table definitions in fact match the database).

If you want to do an actual migration of the database, then you need to make sure you do not have `migrate_enabled=False` in the call to `DAL()`, nor `migrate=False` in the relevant `db.define_table()` calls. Unless you explicitly set those to false, migrations are enabled by default.

Always a good idea to back up your database before doing a migration.

Comment: what will be better solution for that now i m not able to alter my database

Comment: What happens if you remove the `fake_migrate_all=True` and delete the .table file of the relevant table and then make a request to trigger a migration?